# Learning path to the proof of the Weil Conjectures and étale topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, self-learning, arithmetic-geometry

Assume you are an algebraic geometry advanced student who has mastered **Hartshorne**'s book supplemented on the arithmetic side by the introduction of **Lorenzini** - "*An Invitation to Arithmetic Geometry*" and by **Liu** - "*Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*".

- What would be a good learning path towards the proof of the Weil Conjectures for algebraic varieties (not just curves)?
- What modern references are available and in which order should be studied?

Besides the original **Deligne**'s [article I](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=PMIHES_1974__43__273_0) and [article II](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=PMIHES_1980__52__137_0) and **Dwork**'s [result on rationality](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2372974), there is the book **Freitag/Kiehl** - "*Étale Cohomology and the Weil Conjecture*" and the [online pdf](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/lec.html) by **Milne** - "*Lectures on Étale Cohomology*". The first title is out of stock and hard to get and the second seems to me too brief and succinct.

- Is it better to master étale cohomology by itself elsewhere and then refer to the original articles? Is any further algebraic/arithmetic background necessary?
- What other uses and benefits would have studying étale topology for someone not specializing in arithmetic geometry but in complex algebraic geometry?

Thank you in advance for any hints on how to approach such a study program, and for any related advice towards a self-learning path in arithmetic geometry. (*This question is [cross-posted to mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114034/learning-path-for-the-proof-of-the-weil-conjectures) so all kind of students and professionals can provide their advice regardless of their membership to these forums.*)

Comment: [Crossposted to MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/114034/learning-path-for-the-proof-of-the-weil-conjectures).

Comment: @ZhenLin: Is crossposting a bad practice for this type of questions?

Comment: @Javier: crossposting is bad for any type of question. It encourages unnecessary duplication of effort.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: should I remove the question from one of the two sites?

Comment: @Javier: well, it's less bad now that you've indicated the crossposting. But please avoid doing this in the future. Post on one site, then wait awhile and see if you get any good answers before posting it on the other if that, and whenever you do so, link them.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: all right, I shall do so and be aware of this from now on. Thank you for the warning.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Edit (2020 July 27)**: Check out the AMS Open Math Notes on the Weil Conjectures [**here**](https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes/omn-view-listing?listingId=110831). The PDF can be downloaded without signing in or even having an AMS membership.

Pasting an image of the **Contents** from the start of the above-mentioned notes:

[image]

[image]

---

**Edit (2016 March 15):** Another great source to read over is Tao's [**blog post**](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/05/13/dworks-proof-of-rationality-of-the-zeta-function-over-finite-fields/) on the subject, which is (appropriately) entitled *Dwork’s proof of rationality of the zeta function over finite fields*.

---

This answer will no doubt be somewhat unsatisfying, but I can't help but put in a plug for Bernard Dwork, who proved the first of the Weil Conjectures (rationality) before Grothendieck and Deligne came along to dispose of the other two.

With regard to a learning path for **Dwork's proof**, I recommend the following three sources:

1. B. Dwork, On the Rationality of the Zeta-Function of an Algebraic Variety, American Journal of Mathematics. 82 (1960), 631-648.
2. N. Koblitz, p-adic Numbers, p-adic Analysis, and Zeta-Functions, Springer-Verlag, New York, 1984.
3. F.Q. Gouvea, p-adic Numbers, Springer-Verlag, New York, 2003.

I did an undergraduate thesis on Dwork's proof, which mostly consisted of going through Koblitz's book and trying to write something easily understandable at the undergraduate level. Whether or not I succeeded in doing so - or producing anything novel in the process - I cannot say for sure (probably not), but if it'd be helpful here is a copy: [**On a Theorem of Dwork**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hsfqjs37o2y9l5a/Dickman%20Thesis.pdf).

With regard to the latter two conjectures, someone more knowledgeable than I will have to intervene and suggest sources. **Edit:** The more knowledgeable response can be found [**here**](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114034/learning-path-for-the-proof-of-the-weil-conjectures).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew about Dwork's article but it is not freely available to get a copy on my own. I would be very grateful if you could email your work to me. How can we do that without disclosing publicly our emails here?